# detect which are the origin location of user

Tags: angular, router, angular-activatedroute

Let's suppose we have an application with a router configured as follows:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: 'supply', component: SupplyListComponent
  },
  {  
    path: 'supply/:id', component: SupplyComponent 
  }
];
```

Each supply can have one or more identifiers inside. Within the *Supplycomponent*, we have a paginator that shows each supply ID, one by one, on a card, changing the URL each time the user clicks on the next button. 
Example:

```
{
  "supply1": [id_1],
  "supply2": [id_2, id_3, id_4]
}
```

If we push *Supply1*, we go to *'/supply/id_1'*. If we push *Supply2*, we to *'/supply/id_2'*, and we can change between ids with the paginator.

We want to access to this SupplyComponent in two ways: from the location *'/supply'* and from another aplication.

What's the problem? If we want to go to *'/supply/id_3'* from another application, we need to use *ActivatedRoute*, take that id and retrieve the information from API. But we only show the *id_3* information, not all the information of Supply2.

Is there any way to 'detect' if the user comes from *'/supply'* or from another application? I've been looking for similar questions, but none fits my need.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by using same root you will not be able to do that alternatives could be

**using query params**

when you change the root on paginator click add some query params for eg.if you'r redirecting like `router.navigate(['yourroute'])` then add param like `router.navigate(['yourroute'],{queryParams:{orgin:'supply1'}})` and then get query params like

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(data=>{
if(data['orgin']){
//request is from your internal app
}
})
```

**using multiple route**

add one more root with same component and add route data

```
  {  
    path: 'supply1/:id', component: SupplyComponent ,data:{origin:'supply1'}
  }
```

and get data in component like

```
this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(data=>{
    if(data['orgin']){
    //request is from your internal app
    }
    })
```

and nevigate to `suply1/yourid` from your paginator

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that I can do it with this. By the way, is there any way to send the query parameter without displaying it in the URL?

Comment: @Aw3same nope you can't